# Change Framelayout top view in runtime

Tags: android, animation, android-framelayout

I have a frameLayout with two child:

```
 <FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="start">

   <ImageView         
      android:id="@+id/iv1"
      android:layout_width="70dp"       
      android:layout_height="70dp"
      android:background="@drawable/snd1"
    />
    <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/iv2"
      android:layout_width="70dp"
      android:layout_height="70dp"
      android:background="@drawable/snd2"
     />
  </FrameLayout>
```

In the code above, iv2 is on top of the iv1. I want to bring iv1 on top of the iv2 in runtime. (using animation)
I have no problem in using animation but how can I bring iv1 on top of iv2 as it is define in xml layout to be behind iv2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the removeView() function to remove the view and then add it back to the FrameLayout with this function :

```
public void addView (View child, int index)
```

Here is the documentation :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View, int)

Set the index to the count of children - 1 to add it to the end. It will the topmost view then.

Comment: tnx for answer but if I remove a view and add it again with new index, then  wont it get invisible from layout when removing and adding?  because I have to do this during animation!

Comment: Yes it will become invisible, but im guessing that its not visible anyways right. iv1 is in the background of iv2. So when you remove iv1 the user wont notice anything.When you do add it back make sure you set its alpha to 0 so its invisible. You can then fade in the view from alpha 0 to alpha 1.